# In JavaScript, String() and adding opreator( like a+'' ) distinction

Tags: javascript, string

First, show code.

```
let a = 123

// step 1, result: b = '123'
let b = String(a)

// step 2, result: c = '123'
let c  = a + ''
```

What's the **difference**?

`Step 1` invoked toString() methods?

If related concepts are involved, I hope you can explain.

Thanks a lot.

(I know that my English is poor, please correct me. )

Comment: There's no difference in the result. The difference between the methods is, that in the former _you're making_ the conversion explicitly, in the latter the conversion _is made_ implicitly.

Comment: In step 1, the internal [ToString] method is called, see [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like a shorcut to cast values.

```
// to String 
'' + 123    // '123' as string
String(123) // '123' as string

// to Number
+'123'        // 123 as number
Number('123') // 123 as number
```

There is no difference between functions and theses relative shortcuts.